# Proving that if $\mathrm{ker}\, RTR^{-1}= \mathrm{ker}\, RSR^{-1}$ then $\mathrm{ker} T = \mathrm{ker}S$.

Tags: linear-algebra, proof-writing, linear-transformations, solution-verification

So I'm currently studying linear algebra and came across this interesting question about proving that if there are two vector spaces $V$ and $W$ with the following transformations: $S, T: V\to V$ are lineartransformations and $R:V\to W$ is an isomorphism, and if  $\mathrm{ker}\, RTR^{-1}= \mathrm{ker}\, RSR^{-1}$ then $\mathrm{ker} T = \mathrm{ker}S$.

I'm not exactly sure how to prove this. One way that came to mind is using the fact that $R$ is isomorphic such that $RR^{-1}=I$ and multiplying each side of $RTR^{-1}$ to get $T$ and just following through by stating that $\therefore$ $T=S$.

I don't think it's a valid proof so I was wondering if there is another way to prove this.

Comment: What's the ‘kernel of two vector spaces’?

Comment: seems like the key is in understanding the meaning of isomorphism. If $R$ is an isomorphism, and $R^{-1}$ is its inverse then isn't $RTR^{-1} = T$ ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The kernel of $RTR^{-1}$ is the subspace of all vectors $x$ such that $RTR^{-1}x=0$. Similarly for $RSR^{-1}$. We are given that these two kernels are equal. We then want to show that if $y$ is in the kernel of $T$ (i.e., $Ty=0$) then $y$ is in the kernel of $S$ (i.e., $Sy=0$). We also want to show if $y$ is in the kernel of $S$ then $y$ is in the kernel of $T$, but this will be the same argument. Together these two will give us that the kernels of $S$ and $T$ are equal.

So how do we show that if $Ty=0$ then $Sy=0$? By multiplying by $R$ and $R^{-1}$ in a `smart' way. Let $z=Ry$, then $y=R^{-1}z$. So we have that $Ty=TR^{-1}z = 0$. Multiply by $R$ on the left of both sides to get $RTR^{-1}z=R0=0$. Now we know that z is in the kernel of $RTR^{-1}$ so it must be in the kernel of $RSR^{-1}$, which means $RSR^{-1}z=0.$ Can you go from here to show that $Sy=0$?

Comment: I'm kinda stuck in a loop, how can we use the fact that $RSR^{-1}z=0$ to show that $Sy=0$? I don't quite see the relevance of the fact :/ could you explain?

Comment: how did we initally have that $Ty=TR^{-1}z$ equal to zero?

Comment: So the fact we are trying to prove is that given any $y$ such that $Ty=0$ we want to show that $Sy=0$. As $R$ is an isomorphism, we can write $y$ as $R^{-1}z$ where $z = Ry$. Then we have that $Ty = T (R^{-1} z)$. Hopefully, that clears that part up. From there we now want to go from $RSR^{-1}z=0$ to $Sy=0$. Well, we can first replace the $R^{-1}z$ by $y$, so we only want to go from $RSy=0$ to $Sy=0$. How do we justify that?